# Moodles can run on MS Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, moodle

We are developing a site on college and college authorities are not giving us permission to deploy the mysql database server as many of the other sites are using MS Access.

But the moodle needs mysql server is it possible to manually create MS Access connectivity to the moodle.

Comment: Try https://www.google.com/search?q=moodle+ms-access

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible. Moodle supports MySQL, MSSQL, Oracle and PostgreSQL. Access is not really a suitable DB for use with a web application and if you are developing any Moodle site without MySQL, then you are being denied the tools you need to do the job.

I would recommend looking for a cheap £5 a month external hosting solution if you can't get the college to play ball. Any one will do as long as it has PHP5 and MySQL.

Comment: Thanks Matt, I think you are too true I am fed up with ms access as well many times query does not work and as you are saying that moodles will not work on the ms access.